# "Failed to create task or type antlib:org.apache.maven.artifact.ant:mvn" error in Ant

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, ant

Ant build failed to run while running the ant tasks in `build.xml`. I got the following error in the console:

```
Buildfile: F:\Eclipse Projects\my_project\build.xml
  [typedef] Could not load definitions from resource org/apache/maven/artifact/ant/antlib.xml. It could not be found.

BUILD FAILED
F:\my_project\build.xml:32: Problem: failed to create task or type antlib:org.apache.maven.artifact.ant:mvn
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.
No types or tasks have been defined in this namespace yet

This appears to be an antlib declaration. 
Action: Check that the implementing library exists in one of:
        -F:\eclipse\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.8.3.v20120321-1730\lib
        -C:\Users\Lucky\.ant\lib
        -a directory added on the command line with the -lib argument
```

I placed the maven-ant-tasks jar file in eclipse plugin's folder and in the WinAnt ANT_HOME/lib directory and also included in the classpath. But it didn't solve my problem and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11538780/1793718) also couldn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

1. Create a `lib` directory in the root of your project and place the [maven-ant-tasks.jar](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.apache.maven%7Cmaven-ant-tasks%7C2.1.3%7Cjar) file inside it.
2. Include the import statement in your `build.xml`

```
<path id="maven-ant-tasks.classpath" path="lib/maven-ant-tasks-2.1.3.jar" />
<typedef resource="org/apache/maven/artifact/ant/antlib.xml" uri="antlib:org.apache.maven.artifact.ant" classpathref="maven-ant-tasks.classpath" />
```

The above steps solved my issue. Hope this is helpful to someone in the future.

Alternate solutions,

- You can also place the `maven-ant-tasks.jar` file under the `ANT_HOME/lib` folder to solve this issue.
- Or you could have it under the eclipse plugins folder. 
  eg. `eclipse\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.8.3.v20120321-1730\lib`

Answer (score 5):

In my case, i already had the maven-ant-taksk.jar into directory `'eclipse\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.8.3.v20120321-1730\lib'.`

I'm using eclipse, so what i needed was, go to Ant Runtime on menu Windows > Preferences > Ant > Runtime, select `"Ant Home Entries"`, click on `"Ant Home"`button e select the Ant home directory

```
'eclipse\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.8.3.v20120321-1730\lib'
```

It worked!